# What is causing this error "Evaluator.java:6: error: cannot find symbol import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams;"?

Tags: java, antlr4

```
import java.io.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;


public class Eval {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.print("Usage: file");
        } else {
            String file = args[0];
            GrammarParser parser = getParser(file);
            ParseTree AbstractSynTree = parser.prog();
            AntlrToProgram programVisitor = new AntlrToProgram();
            Program prg = programVisitor.visit(AbstractSynTree);

        }

    }

    public static GrammarParser getParser(String file) {
        GrammarParser parser = null;
        try {
            CharStream input = CharStreams.fromFileName(file);
            GrammarLexer lexer = new GrammarLexer(input);
            CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
            parser = new GrammarParser(tokens);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return parser;
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Eval.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams;
                           ^
  symbol:   class CharStreams
  location: package org.antlr.v4.runtime
Eval.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
            CharStream input = CharStreams.fromFileName(file);
                               ^
  symbol:   variable CharStreams
  location: class Eval
2 errors
```

while compiling Eval.java. I am not sure what is going on since all the other Antlr classes are being imported, so I assume the class path has been imported properly. Would appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source of [CharStreams](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/CharStreams.html), you can see it is introduced in ANTLR 4.7. You're most probably using an ANTLR version below that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!!!! Turns out I had the wrong version of antlr in my classpath.